# how set suspend an application automatically ? for security purpose

Tags: android, suspend

is it possible to set auto-suspend an android application? the idea is to create an application which can suspend itself, when the login password is entered incorrectly more than 6 times. this is for security purpose, which unable the user to use application anymore. the reason behind this idea, because the idea of the smartphones might be access by unauthorized user or the smartphone suspected has been stolen.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "suspend".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to keep track of login attempts and check this value each time the login `Activity` starts. If it equals 6, or whatever number you choose, then show a `Dialog` informing the user of the issue and how to fix (or however you want to handle that). In the `Dialog` you can have one `Button` which on click it closes the Application (just call `finish()` on that `Activity`.

Each time the login fails just add 1 to the previous value of that `SharedPreference`.

If this isn't what you need then, as CommonsWare said, " define what you mean by 'suspend'"

Comment: 'suspend' means that the application can't be use anymore. 
it's a last resort security if the smart device has been stolen. similar with the idea, that you would rather have your laptop destroy if it were to be stolen, than having your data/info in hands of other people/thieves.